# Create a dynamic Wizard with links to download pdf files

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to create a report button in:

- view:  account_payment.view_payment_order_form
- model: payment.order

Accounting -> Payment -> Rec. Payment order -> FORM

My goal is to obtain each line of 'line_ids' and open a Wizard that populates with a download link for each line of 'line_ids'.

For the moment I'm trying to create a dynamic Wizard with no luck. I don't know if it is possible to do this.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: What you mean with dynamic?. If you mean that you need a wizard with data on it when you raise it, yes you can, but you need to specify a bit more.

Comment: When the wizard appears I need to create some fields dynamically with links to download a PDF file. Each link is a 'line_id' of a payment.order model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wizard model:

```
class my_wizard(osv.TransientModel):
    _name = 'my_wizard'

    _columns = {
        'line_ids': fields.one2many('payment.order', 'Payment order'),
    }
```

Call wizard (in "payment.order" model):

```
def call_wizard(self, cr, uid, ids, context):

        my_wizard_form_id = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'account_payment', 'my_wizard_form')[1]

        lines = []
        for line in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context).line_ids:
            lines.append([0, 0, {'line_id': line.id}])

        #To create records dyamically   
        ctx={'default_line_ids': lines} 

        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'my_wizard',
            'views': [(my_wizard_form_id, 'form')],
            'view_id': my_wizard_form_id,
            'target': 'new',
            'context': ctx,
        }
```

Wizard view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="my_wizard_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">my_wizard.form</field>
            <field name="model">my_wizard</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml" >
                <form>
                    <field name="line_ids" widget="one2many_list">
                                <tree editable="bottom">
                                    <field name="id"/>
                                    <!-- define "download" function in "payment.line"
                                    <button name='download' type='object' string='download' />
                                </tree>
                    </field>
                        <field name='' />
                    </group>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="action_my_wizard_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name"></field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">my_wizard</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="target">new</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Button to call wizard (payment_order view):

```
<button name='call_wizard' type="object" string="WIZARD"  />
```

You should create `download` method in payment.line model.

```
def download(self, cr, uid, ids, context):
     #To open an URL
     '''return {
        "type": "ir.actions.act_url",
        "url": "LINK TO PDF",
        "target": "self",
    }
    '''

    #To generate a report
    datas = {
        'ids': ids,
        'model': 'dossier',
        'form': self.read(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context)
    }

    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
        'report_name': 'my_report',
        'datas': datas,
        'nodestroy': True
    }
```

I hope this will be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to test soon. If it works(it seems to yes) I will tick as answer.

Comment: @Elektro Is this useful.

Comment: Yes, sorry for this delay.